# How to get rid of unwanted url message in jQuery slider?

Tags: jquery, slider, message

I use Windows 7.  When I mouse-over a jQuery slider's movable handle in my running program, a message appears in the lower left corner of the screen in Chrome26 and FF19 but not in IE10. The message is just the running program's url followed by a #.  The effect can be seen in the documentation demo at the end of http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/. I would much appreciate learning of a way to get rid of that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".ui-slider-handle" ).removeAttr("href");
```

But I think there is a reason for `href` to be set on '#'.

Comment: Thanks, @Ogrim!  That solved the problem and also gave me the words I needed to search and further understand the problem.  I am a lone developer.  I do not need the href.  Thanks again.